# How to access results from a realm in swift

Tags: swift, realm

How do I access objects stored in realm?

I have a realm class "SubscriptionClass":

```
class SubscriptionClass: Object {
   @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId //the primary key
   @Persisted var subscription_number = 0
   @Persisted var question: String = ""
   @Persisted var option1: String = ""
```

with 2 instances:

```
let sub1 = SubscriptionClass()
sub1.subscription_number = 1  //<- the subscription number
sub1.question = "What is 3 * 3"
sub1.option1 = "9"

let sub2 = SubscriptionClass()
sub1.subscription_number = 2
sub1.question = "What is 5 * 5"
sub1.option1 = "25"

let realm = try! Realm()
realm.write {
   realm.add(sub1)
   realm.add(sub2)
}
```

I can get the results of the main SubscriptionClass:

```
let gplSubclassResults = realm.objects(SubscriptionClass.self)
```

However, how do I access the results of either sub1 or sub2?

Comment: Please add the blueprint of Question class

Comment: My prior answer had the wrong terminology in it - I used the word *Subclass* but what you're actually doing is creating *instances* of your class, not subclasses. My apologies.  A subclass extends the functionality of the superclass and what you're doing here are instances. It doesn't affect the answer but it's a FYI - I updated the question.

Comment: This `realm.objects(Question.self)` will retrieve all of the `Question` objects, and will not retrieve the `SubscriptionClass` objects. The pattern for retrieving objects from Realm is identical for all objects - whether they be main classes or subclasses. In this case there are no subclasses (see my above comment) so the pattern to retrieve *all* `SubscriptionClass` objects is `let results = realm.objects(SubscriptionClass.self)` if you want to retrieve sub1 or sub2 and you know the object _id, see the answer from @talha_kuet. If you don't know the _id, you will need to use a filter.

Comment: my apologies, I edited the question to have SubscriptionClass.self

Comment: Very good. Now I believe the question answers itself - *I can get the results of the main SubscriptionClass...how do I access the results of either sub1 or sub2?* - those results will contain sub1 and sub2. If you want a specific sub, you would want to add a filter `.where { $0.subscription_number == "2" }`. See [filtering](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/realm-swift-query-api/) for more info. When responding to a comment here on SO, to get that persons attention respond with an 'at' sign before their name, like @Jay

Comment: Much appreciated & will read more about filtering. Also @Jay, how does the code below compare to adding a filter?

Comment: The code in @talha_kuet answer does not filter. It's instructs Realm to read a specific object by its primary key; this is useful to read a specific object when the primary key is known. A filter is a lot 'heavier' and has more overhead. A filter will query all of the objects that match a given parameter (per my example above) and will return those objects; for example `person.name == 'Jay'` will return ALL Jay objects.

Comment: @Jay How do you filter a realm subclass? I posted it as a separate question to give credit to the right answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71991394/how-to-filter-a-realm-subclass-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve specific `SubscriptionClass` by providing it's id which is used as primary key.

```
realm.object(ofType: SubscriptionClass.self, forPrimaryKey: id)
```

Comment: How would you then filter the subclass? For example, for a question: "What is 5 * 5"? @talha_kuet