# How to filter a realm subclass swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm, filtering, subclass

How do I filter a subclass in realm for swift?

I have a realm class "SubscriptionClass":

```
class SubscriptionClass: Object {
   @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var subscriptionId = "" //the primary key
   @Persisted var subscription_number = 0
   @Persisted var question: String = ""
   @Persisted var option1: String = ""
```

with 2 instances:

```
let sub1 = SubscriptionClass()
sub1.subscriptionId = "Grade 1" //<- the primary key
sub1.subscription_number = 1  //<- the subscription number
sub1.question = "What is 3 * 3"
sub1.option1 = "9"

let sub2 = SubscriptionClass()
sub2.subscriptionId = "Grade 2"
sub2.subscription_number = 2
sub2.question = "What is 5 * 5"
sub2.option1 = "25"

let realm = try! Realm()
realm.write {
   realm.add(sub1)
   realm.add(sub2)
}
```

To access main SubscriptionClass:

```
let allSubscriptionClassResults = realm.objects(SubscriptionClass.self)
```

To access the specific subclass:

```
let sub1ClassResults = realm.object(ofType: SubscriptionClass.self, forPrimaryKey: subscriptionId)
```

However, to make it more efficient, how do I filter for items in the subclass for example the question that is "What is 5*5"?

Comment: Doesn't `object(ofType: forPrimaryKey:)` return only ONE object, while `objects(_;)` returns an array (or more specically a `Results`) of them? You can use `filter(_:)` on the "array".

Comment: Please note this `let sub1 = SubscriptionClass()` is NOT a subclass. It's an instance of the SubscriptionClass. A subclass would be a class that inherits the SubscriptionClass model and provides additional functionality. So this *To access the specific subclass:* should be *To access a specific object*. And likewise this statement *To access main SubscriptionClass* should be *To return all SubscriptionClass objects*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually multiple questions here. First we need to change the use of of the word `subclass` to `instance`. There are no subclasses in the question.

Note that Realm is conceptually an `Object' database so we're going to use the word 'object' to refer the objects stored in Realm (the 'instances' when they've been loaded in to memory)

I will rephrase each for clarity:

> 1. How do I return all `SubscriptionClass` objects?

```
let results = realm.objects(SubscriptionClass.self)
```

> 2. How do I return one specific `SubscriptionClass` object if I know the
>    primary key?

```
let oneObject = realm.object(ofType: SubscriptionClass.self, forPrimaryKey: theObjectsPrimaryKey)
```

> 3. How do I return all of the `SubscriptionClass` objects that match a
>    specific criteria; where the question property equals `What is 5*5`

```
let results = realm.objects(SubscriptionClass.self).filter("question == 'What is 5*5'")
```

and I will slide in #4: this queries for all questions as in #3 but only returns the very first one it finds. This can be dangerous because Realm objects are unordered so if there are ever more than one object, it could return a different first object each time it's used

```
if let oneObject = realm.objects(SubscriptionClass.self).filter("question == 'What is 5*5'").first {
    //do something with the object
}
```

Subclass:

A subclass inherits the superclass's functionality and extends it to provide additional functionality. Here's a subclass that adds a difficulty property to a subclass of SubscriptionClass (the 'super class')

```
class SubscriptionWithDifficultySubClass: SubscriptionClass {
   var difficulty = ""  //Easy, Medium, Hard etc
}
```

and then a different subclass that provides a subject property:

```
class SubscriptionWithSubjectSubClass: SubcriptionClass {
  var subject = ""  //Math, Grammar, Science etc
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer & I understand. If I have multiple questions in the Grade 1 subscription then I will have to filter for the "Grade 1" questions. If know the primary key then I can search for a specific object.

Answer (score 1):

Search object by `primary_key` gives you only one specific object if it exists or it returns `nil`. And it's time complexity in ***O(1)***.

No filter option is more efficient than this. Because under the hood it works like look upon a dictionary and return the object it exists. In case of `filter` it works like iterating over the objects in the DB and return the matched objects.

If you want to `filter` objects with other property which is not `primary_key` then it returns an array of objects which is already commented by @Larme. But it's time complexity is ***O(n)***. Here is the code

```
let objects = realm.objects(SubscriptionClass.self).filter("question == What is 5 * 5")

objects.forEach { object in
    // do whatever you want
    print(object)
}
```

If there is only one object with a specific value of a property (not primary_key) then you can access the object using `filter` like below.

```
if let object = realm.objects(SubscriptionClass.self).filter("question == What is 5 * 5").first {
    // do whatever you want
    print(object)
}
```